# Is it possible to have two id in html by putting a space between them?

Tags: html, css-selectors

Can I use space to separate two id's?

```
<div class="g2 "> 
    <input type="text" id="noPosting number_only" disabled="true" name="post_every" value="" class="txt_r integer-365"/>
</div>
```

Comment: No you cant have two ID's on one element . . Use atribute for example `data-id=""`

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you show an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Putting a space in the ID value doesn't automatically make them two different IDs for the element. They can still be selected in CSS through `#noPosting\ number_only` (notice the `\` which escapes the blank space). They can also be selected in Javascript through something like `document.getElementById('noPosting number_only')`.

```css
#noPosting\ number_only {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="g2 ">
  <div id="noPosting number_only">test</div>
</div>
```

If you need to have separate selectors, it is better to use a class selector instead. Alternatively, you could use the attribute selector to select such an element through the two parts of the value. See the example below:

```css
[id*=noPosting] {
  color: red;
}
[id*=number_only] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="g2 ">
  <div id="noPosting number_only">test</div>
</div>
```

---

You can read more about this here: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

No, only one unique ID will work in HTML per element. But you can use more than one class in a single element in HTML, separated by space.